# Trying KMM - Kdoctor: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

So I'm messing around with [KMM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-setup.html#check-your-environment), and trying to use [Kdoctor](https://github.com/Kotlin/kdoctor) as the official docs suggests to run a diagnostic whether my environment is well set.

**When I run it I get the following diagnostic:**

```
Environment diagnose (to see all details, use -v option):
[✓] Operation System
[✓] Java
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] Xcode
[✖] Cocoapods
  ✖ CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.zprofile
    export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

When I try to add the UTF-8 encoding with the following command **~/.zprofile** I get the following permission error:

```
adam@Adam-MacBook-Pro ~ % ~/.zprofile
zsh: permission denied: /Users/adam/.zprofile
adam@Adam-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

This is literally my first day on a Mac, so everything is new for me on here.
How can I give permission to .zprofile?

I've read that if I drag and drop a folder to the terminal I can set reading/writing permissions but I cannot find that folder, guess it is hidden?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

After running `cat ~/.zprofile`

all I see in the terminal is:

```
eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

What is it supposed to mean?

**EDIT 2:**

I managed to add UTF-8 to both **zprofile and zsh** now I see this:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

But the error still remains with cocoapods.

Answer (score 1):

if you already managed to add

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

into `~/.zprofile` then you have to close the terminal and reopen it. Otherwise, you can use the following command:

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

this way the permission error will disappear and the locale stuff will be fixed.

Comment: How can I check whether I added the encodings successfully? I've added them to zprofile or zshrc, don't know what are these things by the way this is my first day on Mac.

Comment: `cat ~/.zprofile` and double check if the `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` command is listed.